# Is it normal to throw an exception over soap webservice server to the client?

Tags: web-services, exception

I am writing a webservice server (c# soap) to my system and I wonder if it is ok to throw `new RequestDataNotValidException("Email not valid")` to the client?

1. I know that c# and java clients will handle it very good, but PHP for example will not know how to catch this exception, should i?
2. if so, is it acceptable to throw exception on data validation problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exceptions in SOAP are more or less handled using SOAP faults. In principle fault is just an alternative response message declared explicitly in WSDL. Faults are part of the SOAP messaging protocol and every SOAP-compliant client should handle them in some way.

Comment: Thanks, but how do i use fault? I guess it is not `throw new Exception()`, thanks

Comment: It depends on your technology, if you are coding *contract-first* then defining fauls in WSDL will generate appropriate exception. If you throw them from your WS method they will be translated into fauls by the WS stack.

Comment: Can you post a link to an article that explains these two methods? thanks